# Bypass the use of Domain in WinEXE

Tags: linux, windows, winexe

is there a way to bypass the use of domain in the winexe command?:

```
winexe -U domain/username%password  //hostname "cmd.exe"
```

I have two PCs. one is running on windows and the other in linux. These two machines does not have a domain server. Just a simple local area network. Both PCs have administrative accounts
Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After exploring, I finally resolved the issue by using .\ as a variable for the domainname. the .\ is a default value for the local area network.